# Monotonicity with Euclidean distance

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, monotone-functions

We have a curve $y=f(x)>0$ and a moving point along the $x$ axis. For every position of the point, we find the nearest point on the curve, let $(x',f(x'))$, in the sense of the Euclidean distance.

Can we show that $x'$ is a monotonic (possibly discontinuous) function of $x$ ?

[image]

Comment: Hint: by contradiction.

Comment: @Adayah: mh, can you tell more ?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous then $x'$ may fail to exist. E.g. if $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ne 0$  then there is no nearest $(x',f(x'))$ to $(0,0).$.... If $f$ is continuous then $x'$ need not be unique so the Q is whether  we can define a monotonic $g(x)$ such that $ d(\;(x,0),\;(g(x),f(g(x))\;)=\min_u d(\;(x,0),\;(u,f(u)\;).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: you can assume $f$ continuous and $x'$ unique, except at a finite number of points.

Comment: What about $x$ moving along the diameter of a circle? That at least shows discontinuity (and piecewise-constantness) is possible.

Comment: @Chappers: I am not interested in such limit cases (though I mentioned possible discontinuities). Assume no constant curvature.

Comment: Ok, I guess my hint wasn't very helpful, since the question turned out to be a bit harder than I initially assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a purely algebraic solution:

Let $h(x, a) = (x-a)^2 + f(x)^2$ so $\displaystyle a' = \mathop{\operatorname{argmin}}_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h(x, a)$. Let $a_1 < a_2$. Note that

$$h(x, a_2) - h(x, a_1) = (a_2-x)^2 - (a_1-x)^2 = (a_2-a_1)(a_2+a_1-2x).$$

This is a decreasing function of $x$. Now suppose for contradiction that $a_2' = x_1 < x_2 = a_1'$. Then

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
x_2 = a_1' & \implies & \phantom{ h(x_2, a_2) \: - } \: h(x_2, a_1) \leqslant \phantom{h(x_1, a_2) \: - } \: h(x_1, a_1) \\
x_1 < x_2 & \implies & h(x_2, a_2) - h(x_2, a_1) < h(x_1, a_2) - h(x_1, a_1) \\ \hline
& & h(x_2, a_2) \: \phantom{ - \: h(x_2, a_1) } < h(x_1, a_2)
\end{array}$$

So $x_1 \neq \mathop{\operatorname{argmin}}_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h(x, a_2)$, contradiction.

---

This solution has a [nice illustration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bt45ql9zin) if $f(x)$ is smooth. For a fixed $a$ the point $a'$ will be $x$ such that $h(x, a)$ is minimal. If you fix $x_1 < x_2$ and move $a$ continuously to the right, you'll note that $h(x_1, a)$ and $h(x_2, a)$ are moving up or down, but $h(x_2, a)$ is always moving faster down (or slower up) than $h(x_1, a)$, since

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} a} h(x_2, a) = 2(a-x_2) < 2(a-x_1) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} a} h(x_1, a).$$

So if $x_2$ minimizes $h(x, a_1)$, and we move from $a_1$ to a point $a_2$ to the right, $x_2$ can never be worse than any point $x_1 < x_2$, because it started better and was moving better.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Picture:

[image]

$X=(x',f(x'))$ is the closest point to $x$. $y$ is a point to the right of $x$.

Where can $Y$, the closest point to $y$ lie?

- It must be outside (or on) the circle through $X$ centred at $x$ (dark brown), or $X$ would not be the closest point to $x$.
- It must be inside (or on) the circle through $X$ centred at $y$ (red), or it wouldn't be closer to $y$ than $X$ is.

But the only region where these are both true is the lune on the right (including its boundary). In particular, none of this possible region lies on the left of the green line, so $Y$ cannot be to the left of $X$. Hence the function is monotonic, for this positioning.

This works for any position of the two points provided $y>x$, since the circles will always be the same way round, and only intersect on the green line.

Comment: Don't you think that if $X$ goes to the right of $x$, the lune goes to the left ?

Comment: The relative position of the circles depends on the relative position of $x$ and $y$. $X$ is essentially just the intersection point. Other case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/laC9g.png

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer. To show that $x'$ may be definable but not  uniquely definable and may be monotonic but discontinuous, when $f$ is continuous.

Let $f(x)=\sqrt {1-x^2}\;$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ and let $f(x+2)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

If $x\in \mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Z$ or if $x$ is an odd integer then the unique nearest $(u,f(u))$ to $(x,0)$ is  $(x',f(x'))$ where $x'$ is the  $nearest$   integer to $x.$ (If $x$ is an odd integer then $(x,0)=(x,f(x))$ and $x'=x.$).

If $x$ is an even integer  we may choose $x'$ to be any member of $[x-1,x+1]$ as all points of $\{(u,f(u): |u-x|\leq 1\}$ lie on the semi-circle of radius $1$ centered at $(x,0).$

Then $x'$ is defined and monotonic but cannot be  continuous  because if $x$ is an even integer then $\{z':z\in [x-1,x)\}=\{x-1\}$ and $\{z':z\in (x,x+1]\}=\{x+1\}.$

Comment: The question is about monotonicity. Discontinuity is known to be possible.

Comment: It occurs to me that for any continuous $f$ we may let $m(x)=\min_u d(\;(x,0),\;(u,f(u))\;)$  and let $x'=\sup\{v:\; d(\;(x,0),\;(u,f(u)\;)=m(x)\}$  but right now I have no time.